Wifi LED Smart Bulb
I'm trying to use my smart wifi bulb ESP8266 as a wireless controller for RGB LED. Currently it's a 9 W bulb works from 220 V AC.
My question is, if I disassemble the ESP8266 board from it and use it by help of FET to control.
All I want is to increase control the wattage and apparently the light without buying extra bulbs.


This is what i want to achieve
To control the 6bulb of 12v 10watt each with the help of esp8266, which is DESOLDERED from bulb.
I know i have to use the voltage regulator for dropping the 12v to 3.3 and also fet to make the 12v led bulb work with dimming control

So please suggest what fet should i use for this project also if this will work (the esp from wifi bulb)

what is your question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You're best bet is to get and RGB LED controller for what you are trying to do rather than modify that light - first, It will be difficult to do that, second that circuit is likely non-isolated from mains so you have a real safety hazard on your hands (literally).

BMS - Hi, You posted an "answer", but it was really part of the question. Therefore it should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box & it has been moved into the question as an edit i.e. as an update instead. || Unless you are writing the full & final conclusion to your own question, without using any other answers (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should [edit] the question to add new information or updates etc. (unless that would invalidate existing answers, if any). TY
